# How to perform a contour integral for propagators (Peskin section 2.4)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, propagator

I am currently studying Quantum field theory and I have a problem understunding the way some integrals are performed. I am talking about the ones involving Green functions.

I can't understand the reason behind the different contours. Take for example equation (2.54) of Peskin & Schroeder. 
\begin{align}
<0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0> &= \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\bigg\{\frac{1}{2E_{\textbf{p}}}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)} \bigg|_{p^0=E_{\textbf{p}}}+\frac{1}{-2E_{\textbf{p}}}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)} \bigg|_{p^0=-E_{\textbf{p}}}\bigg\}\\
&\underset{x^0>y^0}{=} \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\int\frac{dp^0}{2\pi i}\frac{-1}{p^2-m^2}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}
\end{align}

I don't understand the reason for $x^0>y^0$ going from the first line to the second. Then he explains two different types of contour as you can see in the following figure, as well as another Feynman contour.

[image]

If anyone can clear this confusion for me, I will be thankful :)

Comment: In order to use Jordan's lemma (i.e. the circular part of the integral vanishes) one needs to use two different contours depending on the sign of the number in the exponent

Comment: What I don't understand in the figures, is the little semi cercles. Why is some of them up the others are down? and why does the Feynman contour has one up and one down?

Comment: Aha, you want to avoid singularities in and on the contour to ensure that the function is analytic througout the integration region. Strictly speaking therefore you also need to show that the integrals over the semi circles go to zero in the limit of the corresponding radii going to zero

Comment: If $x^0<y^0$ then the countour must be closed on the opposite side (in order to avoid a contribution to the integral from the arc at infinity)

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I got the idea.